# Special linear lie algebra relative with Angular Momentum

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let have the special linear algebra $\operatorname{Sl}(2,\mathbb F)$ ,which is the set of $ 2 \times 2$ matrix with trace zero. I have to prove that the lie algebra $ g=\operatorname{Span}\{ L_1,L_2,L_3\}=\mathbb CL_1+\mathbb CL_2+\mathbb CL_3$ where $ L_1,L_2,L_3$ are Angular Momentum, is the $ Sl(2,\mathbb C)$.

Contrariwise the set  $ g=\operatorname{Span}\{ L_1,L_2,L_3\}=\mathbb RL_1+\mathbb RL_2+\mathbb RL_3$ is not the $\operatorname{Sl}(2,\mathbb R)$

I am trying to choose $h,x,y$ as linear combination of  $ L_1,L_2,L_3$ such that: $[h,x]=2x , [h,y]=-2y , [x,y]=h$ , but i cant find the way .Can anyone help me? Thanks..

Comment: I seem to recall $L_1,L_2,L_3$ involve complex entries (I guess there are a few different representation choices here, but, I think they all have complex entries in at least one of these, maybe two) so what are you saying about $g$? Is it that you want to show $g$ is not Lie algebra isomorphic to $sl(2, \mathbb{R})$ ? I don't think the real span of the angular momentum is closed under bracket (need complex scalars)...

Comment: My idea is to write $ h = a_1L_1+ b_1L_2+ c_1L_3 , x = a_2L_1+ b_2L_2+ c_2L_3 , y = a_3L_1+ b_3L_2+ c_3L_3 $ and using the property of the angular momentum ,in the brachets relation $ [h,x]=2x,[h,y]=-2y[x,y]=h $ to try to find $ a_i,b_i,c_i $ but it is not easy..